# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames - Webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Starting from a list I would like to query a webpage to extract the tags from each listing. The results should be saved on a csv file. However, I come across this error: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames.

My understanding is that the dictionary that comes from the query contains more keys than the field names although the dictionary has a variable number of keys depending on the listing.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from parsel import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from collections import defaultdict

####### reading from the input file ##########

columns = defaultdict(list)  # each value in each column is appended to a list

# get the list of keywords from the csv file
with open('query.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  # read rows into a dictionary format
for row in reader:  # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
    for (k, v) in row.items():  # go over each column name and value
        columns[k].append(v)  # append the value into the appropriate list

# the list containing all of the keywords
search_query_list = columns['Keyword']

########## start scraping ###############

rb_results = []

# create a driver and let it open google chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

# get linkedin website
driver.get('https://www.redbubble.com/')
sleep(0.5)


for i in range(len(search_query_list)):

next_query = search_query_list[i]

# get RB website
driver.get('https://www.redbubble.com/')

# get the search by its id
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("query")

sleep(0.5)

# enter the query to the search bar
search_bar.send_keys(next_query)

# press enter
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(1)


# from parsel's selector get the page source
sel1 = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sleep(0.5)

# first shirt //
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('shared-components-ShopSearchSkeleton-ShopSearchSkeleton__composedComponentWrapper--1s_CI').click()
sleep(1)

sel2 = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sleep(0.5)

################## get TAGS ###############

# Check tags for all products
try:
    # get the tags for the search query   
    tags_rb = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf").extract_first()

       # if number of products is found print it and search for the prime
    # print the number of products found
    if tags_rb == None:
        rb_results.append("0")

    else:

        rb_results = str(tags_rb)

except:
 rb_results.append("error")   

###### writing part ########
with open ("rb_results.csv","w", newline='') as resultFile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(resultFile, fieldnames=["Rb Results"],delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerows({'Rb Tags': item} for item in rb_results)

    resultFile.close()
```

How can I solve the issue with the error message: ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Rb Tags'?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The keys used in `writerows` need to be listed somewhere in `fieldnames`.  Right now `fieldnames=["Rb Results"]`, and `"Rb Tags"` is not in that list. Assuming you just want the one key, you should replace `"Rb Tags"` with `"Rb Results"` (or the other way around).

Comment: thank you so much! it works! the issue I face is that it should extract all the tags of the class shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf (from the website). Instead, I see that it applies the last conditions of if. That is: except:
 rb_results.append("error").

Maybe, it is a newbie question as I am pretty new to this but how can I make sure that the csv captures all the tags contained in that class name?